# Circular text around a circle image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

#### Context:

Tyring to put a SVG path text on top of a circle image.
A square picture is rounded up useing `rounded-circle`. A SVG path is drawn around it and use to write a text. Resulting in :

[image]

#### Code: https://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4jkt/

```
<div class="mt-3 row">
    <div class="col-9 CircleThing" style="background-color: coral;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/" alt="contact" class="rounded-circle">
        <svg width="600" height="600">
            <!--Base circle for the text-->
            <!--<circle id="curve" cx="270" cy="270" r="260" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />--> 
            <path id="curve" fill="transparent"
                  d="M 10, 270        
                  a 260,260 0 1,0 520,0
                  a 260,260 0 1,0 -520,0 " />
            <text width="520">
                <textPath xlink:href="#curve"  >
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Css:

```
 .CircleThing {
  font-family: Gill Sans Extrabold;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

#### Issue:

In my last try I have multiple issue:
1/. The svg is not on top of the img.
2/. The text start in the bottom left corner while I want it to in the right. 
To create the path I first did a SVG circle and after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d deduce it path to be :

```
M cx, cy
a r,r 0 1,0 (r * 2),0
a r,r 0 1,0 -(r * 2),0
```

3/. The text is upside down or Inside out. for the top right quatter

Comment: try to set the svg to position absolute left:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. Please note that I've reversed the `#curve` for the `textPath`. Also I've moved the image inside the SVG and rounded with `clipPath`. This is important if you need to make it responsive.

```css
svg{width:90vh;}
```

```html
<div class="mt-3 row">
  <div class="col-9 CircleThing" style="background-color: coral;">
    <svg viewBox="-30 -30 600 600" style="background-color: black;">
<defs>
<path id="curve" d="M 10, 270 a 260,260 0 1,1 520,0 a 260,260 0 1,1 -520,0 " />
<clipPath id="clip">
<path d="M 40, 270a 230,230 0 1,0 460,0a 230,230 0 1,0 -460,0 " />
</clipPath>
</defs>
     
<image xlink:href="https://via.placeholder.com/500/" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
          
<text fill="white" font-size="40">
<textPath xlink:href="#curve" >
    some words
</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ho, I didn't knew about image in SVG. It's a great idea as I can easly handle those as they have the same center than the text. [This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ZJA.png) really sumarize the part on `large-arc-flag` and `sweep-flag` that I miss understood in the documentation. from this [blender question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41973/). Everything was more clear once I stop reading html spec and start reading Illustrator and blender explanation about svg..

Comment: Ps: Img is not load on IE/Edge. Not a big deal. But I had to wrote it as it's just a back square that can be confusing for people on IE/Edge.