# Writing styling from circle and text elements in a CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a `circle` and `text` element that have x and y coordinates set as 50%. I want to write the coordinates in the CSS file and not the JS file but i cannot find the equivalent, i only get `position`, `background-position-y` or `background-position-x` but not `position-x` or `position-y`

I've noticed that in the elements the coordinates are written in a different way

```
    <svg height="24" width="24">
     <circle className="application-count" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="12">
     </circle>//Here the coordinates are written as cx and cy
     <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy=".4em">{company.applicationCount}
     </text>//Here the coordinates are written as x and y
    </svg>
```

The CSS file accepts `fill` and `text-anchor` but not radious or coordinates

Comment: That's not really an option in CSS.

Comment: If this is inside an SVG, you may want to add the `svg` tag (Otherwise, I don't believe `circle` is a built in HTML element)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946106/circular-text-around-a-circle-image

Comment: yes @DBS the only attributes the `svg` has is height and witdh which can be written on the CSS file

Comment: i marked it as a duplicate since the javascript tag is used on the question. looks like the solution is to update the attribute x/y values.

Comment: @G-Cyr seems to me this was intended as "text around a circle" rather than "text **in** a circle".

Comment: @Paulie_D i understood he wants to update the x and y values inside the `text` tag. actually set at 50% . did i get it  wrong (my average english ? )

Comment: Frankly, it could be either but the OP does mention "radius" which I assumes meant text on a circle path...hence the link I provided,

Comment: @Paulie_D i think he was looking for a way to update also attributes that have no or not yet equivalence in CSS alike stroke or fill or text-anchor.